# Find difference in dates among entries across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, difference

df1=

```
Date     Team1     Team2
6/1      Boston    New York
6/13     New York  Boston
6/27     Boston    New York
```

I am trying to calculate the number of days since the last time Boston appeared in either column, but I can only figure out how to look it up within one column, using df1['Days since Boston played'] = df1.groupby('Team1')['Date'].diff().fillna(0)

What I would like the output to be:

```
Date     Team1     Team2      Days since Boston played
6/1      Boston    New York   0
6/13     New York  Boston     12
6/27     Boston    New York   14
```

**EDIT - expanding the dataframe to learn how this can be applied to all teams, not just one**
What I would like the output to be:

```
Date     Team1     Team2      Days since **Team1** played
6/1      Boston    New York   0
6/13     New York  Chicago    12
6/27     Boston    New York   14
6/28     Chicago   Boston     15
```

Answer (score 2):

Use isin to check if Boston is present in either team1 or team2 and find timedelta

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%m/%d')

df.loc[df.isin(['Boston']).any(1),'Days since Boston played'] = df.loc[df.isin(['Boston']).any(1), 'Date'].diff().dt.days


    Date        Team1       Team2       Days since Boston played
0   1900-06-01  Boston      New York    NaN
1   1900-06-13  New York    Boston      12.0
2   1900-06-27  Boston      New York    14.0
```

If you want the date column back in original format, you can use strftime

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d')

    Date    Team1       Team2       Days since Boston played
0   06/01   Boston      New York    NaN
1   06/13   New York    Boston      12.0
2   06/27   Boston      New York    14.0
```

Comment: Thank you. this really helps. Is there a way it can also translate to any team. Say I wanted to figure out the difference in dates for whatever team appeared in the Team1 column?

Comment: Can you pl elaborate?

Comment: sure, for the sake of the example I will expand the dataframe in the main post. More or less I want to know how many days rest the team got, regardless of which team it is. How many days rest did Chicago get? Boston? New York? LA? etc... not just one team in focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a groupby on Team1 and then do a difference on the dates:

```
# Note: you should post a creatable example in your post next time 
data = {
    'Date': ['2018-06-01', '2018-06-13', '2018-06-27'],
    'Team1':['Boston', 'New York', 'Boston'], 
    'Team2':['New York', 'Boston', 'New York']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time between games'] = df.groupby('Team1')['Date'].diff().fillna(0)
```

This will actually give you the difference between games for all home teams.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I am looking for the difference in dates for specifically Boston in this case, not just the home team.